# Javascript setInterval for sequential numbers

Tags: javascript

I'm writing some code that looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function write_numbers(){
var count = 1;
var brk = "<br>"
while (count < 1218){
 document.write(count + brk);
 count++;
 }},1000)
</script>
```

I need it to display the first number which is one then wait one second then display the next number (2) then wait a second, I need this to carry on till it reaches 1218 then stop.
With the code I've written it just writes all the numbers up, waits a second then repeats all the numbers again.
I'm quite new to coding so i don't know how to fix this.
If someone could tell me how to do it, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple issues in your code, although you are using `setInterval()`, since you have a while loop inside it, the complete loop will be executed every 1 second.

Instead you need to have the `setInterval()` callback use an `if` statement to check whether to print the value or not like

```js
var count = 1;
var interval = setInterval(function write_numbers() {
  if (count <= 1218) {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(count));
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    count++;
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

two issues

1) If you are using setInterval then you must clear the interval as well otherwise it will be an infinite loop

2) use `if` rather than `while` so that number is printed one by one.

try this

```
var count = 1;
var interval1= setInterval(function write_numbers(){
    var brk = "<br>"
    if (count < 1218)
    {
       document.write(count + brk);
       count++;
    }
    else 
    {  
        count = 1;
       clearInterval(interval1);
    }
},1000);
```

Comment: @Sirko already updated that, using `if` rather than `while` now

Comment: @Sirko it can be done with setTimeout as well,  but I wanted to tell him what he is missing from his current implementation rather than giving a totally new one

Answer (score 0):

The below script should do the trick for you:

```
<script>
var count = 1;
var brk = "<br>";
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000); // This should be a global variable for clearInterval to access it.

function myTimer() {
 document.write(count + brk);
 count++;
 if(count > 1218){
  myStopFunction();
 }
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should define count outside `setInterval`. Defining inside will reset it every time.

Second, `while (count < 1218){}` should be a conditional statement. I have considered `if(count>= 1218)` as termination condition.

Third, when even you use `setInterval`, remember to use `clearInterval` as well.

#### Code

```js
var count = 1;
var interval = setInterval(function write_numbers() {
  var brk = "<br>"

  document.write(count + brk);
  count++;
  if (count >= 10) {
    window.clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code man , only one change from your code.
count variable declare out side of the setInterval function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 1;
    setInterval(function write_numbers(){
        var brk = "<br>"
        if (count < 1218)
        {
           document.write(count + brk);
           count++;
        }

    },1000);
</script>
```